# Do a Custom Animation with UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to implement an animation like the Calendar ipad application but in a bit different way. Is there any sample applications available or can someone suggest me any pdf's which can help?

Comment: I added ios tag, because people are unlikely to see it without that.

Comment: FYI, this question is also a little ambiguous. Not sure if it conforms to the StackOverflow [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading the animation section of the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6). You might also want some familiarity with [gesture recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html), too.

If this doesn't answer your question, you'll have to provide more specifics, examples of the code you're currently using to transition, what you've tried, etc.